# AWS Lambda working with S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to create a Python Lambda function to take uploaded s3 images and create a thumbnail version of them.

I have permission problems where I cannot get access to my bucket. I understand that I need to create a bucket policy. I don't understand how I can make a policy which works for a lambda request performing the thumbnail process?

Comment: You will need to provide more information.  What have you tried so far?  How did it fail?  What does your code look like?

Comment: Instead of using a bucket policy just give the Lambda function's IAM role the permissions needed to access the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want to do the following:

1. Fire lambda whenever the something is uploaded to your bucket
2. Read a file from the bucket
3. Write a (thumbnail) file back to the bucket

You'll need 3 different permissions to do that:

1. The S3 service will need permission to invoke your lambda function (this is done for you when you add an S3 event source via the AWS Lambda console).
2. The lambda execution role (the one selected on the Configuration tab of the Lambda Console) will need read/write access to call S3.  You can generate a policy for this on the [policy generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) by selecting IAM Policy from the drop down and then selecting the S3 permissions you need.
3. For added security, you can set a bucket policy on S3 to only allow the lambda function to access it.  You can generate this from the [policy generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) as well by selecting S3 policy.  You would then enter lambda.amazonaws.com as the Principal.

Comment: If he define the permission in the lambda function's role, does he need to also define it in the bucket policy?